# SCSS Calling Mixin without duplication

Tags: css, foreach, sass, mixins

I am looking to develop this mixin further, so I can pass multiple arguements through the mixin without having to re-create the include every time e.g:

NOT THIS:

```
@include main-container(red);
@include main-container(blue);
```

BUT THIS:

```
@include main-container(red, blue);
```

Current Code

```
@mixin main-container-bg($name){
    &.#{$name}-bg{
        background:url("/images/"#{$name}"-angle-bg.png") center 78px no-repeat;
    }
}
```

I believe I need a for statement alongside an each statement to loop my mixin though all of the arguments in the @include later in the scss.

Any idea's?

Any help is welcomed.

-Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `@each` directive and pass a list to the mixin in this way

```
@mixin main-container-bg($listcolours) {

  @each $colour in $listcolours {
    &.#{$colour}-bg{
      background:url(/images/#{$colour}-angle-bg.png) center 78px no-repeat;
    }  
  }

}


div {
  @include main-container-bg((red, blue));
}
```

---

The generated CSS is

```
div.red-bg {
  background: url(/images/red-angle-bg.png) center 78px no-repeat;
}
div.blue-bg {
  background: url(/images/blue-angle-bg.png) center 78px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: hi Fabrizio thanks for the reply. Could you explain why the @include values have to be in double brackets? Also where $color comes from? I cannot see it defined elsewhere. thanks!

Comment: 1) I used brackets because I need to pass a `list` as a single argument . 2) $colour is the variable with the current colour while  the `@each` statement is running: please read http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive

Comment: thanks, I sorta knew what I wanted to do. But could not get the message to the hands!